# How do CURRVAL and NEXTVAL defaults generate "ORA-0094: column not allowed here" in Oracle 11

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, syntax-error, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using a textbook for Oracle 12c but the course wanted us to download Oracle 11, so I wonder if that is the issue? This is from the textbook which shows the table TEST_DEFVAL created when entered:

```
insert into orders (order#, customer#, orderdate, shipdate, shipstreet, shipcity, shipstate, shipzip)
values (orders_order#_seq.NEXTVAL, 1010, '06-APR-09', NULL, '123 WEST MAIN', 'ATLANTA', 'GA', 30418);

select order#, customer#, orderdate, shipdate, shipstreet, shipcity, shipstate, shipzip
from orders
where customer# = 1010;

insert into orderitems (order#, item#, isbn, quantity, paideach)
values (orders_order#_seq.CURRVAL, 1, 8117949391, 1, 8.50);

select *
from orderitems
where order# = 1021;

create sequence test_defval_seq
    increment by 1
    start with 100
    nocache
    nocycle;

create table test_defval
    (col1 number default test_defval_seq.NEXTVAL, 
    col2 NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, it is 11g that causes the error. You can't use column's default value like that. Workaround is to create a trigger:

```
SQL> create table test_defval (col1 number, col2 number);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence test_defval_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_def
  2    before insert on test_defval
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.col1 := test_defval_seq.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test_defval (col2) values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test_defval;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1        100

SQL>
```